# left and right sidebars overlapping main content using position:fixed

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS.
trying to study some layouts and ran into this issue.

I'm trying to prevent the left and right sidebar(aside) from scrolling. No matter how much I scroll the main, it will always stay there; I've set its position to fixed and it looked all fine. the issue is, the main content is overlapping with the right sidebar(aside) when resizing. I've tried position: relative and absolute to the right and changing it to div but nothing happens.
the goal is - when my chrome browser shrinks, it should show the Horizontal/vertical scrollbars without any overlapping of main contents. no matter how long my main content is, the sidebars should always be there! Thank you in advance!

Here is my code

```css
body, html {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
}
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 120px;
    top: 0;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgb(82, 50, 50);
}
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin-top: 120px;
    top: 0;
    width: 800px;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-right: 400px;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 217, 0);
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    max-width: 1600px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <aside id="sidebar" class="left">
    </aside>   
    <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum blah blah (cutted: about 100lines)
    </div>

    <aside id="sidebar" class="right">
    </aside>   
</div>
```

Comment: Using flex you could achieve the same exact result with a more modern and scalable approach

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `.content` a dynamic width instead of the static one you've set.
Try this

```
.content {
    width: calc(100% - 400px - 400px); /* where 400px and 400px are the width of the sidebars */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `position: fixed` and you are using `px`:

> An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the
> viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the
> page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used
> to position the element.

By using the px, the element size will always be 400px even though the window size is very small. To prevent the content from overlapping to others and keep the same ratio with other elements, you should use `%` which is the percentage for the container's size and it will keep the same ratio between the `aside` and `div` no matter the window size.

Another soluation is to you `media screen`

> The @media CSS at-rule can be used to apply part of a style sheet based on the result of one or more media queries. With it, you specify a media query and a block of CSS to apply to the document if and only if the media query matches the device on which the content is being used.

Check more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

If you want to prevent `aside` from scrolling, just use:

```
aside{
overflow: hideen
}
```